# C# MVC - Contexto diferente

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Bom dia,

tenho dois context DbContextPrincipal e DbContextHist que possuem as classes **Conta** e **ContaHist**, respectivamente. No DbContextPrincipal tem a classe **Cliente**. Gostaria de fazer o join entre ContaHist e Cliente para obter o nome do cliente, porém como é contexto diferente não estou conseguindo.

Comment: apresente o seu código... mas uma join propriamente dita, não faz muito sentido em contextos diferentes

Comment: até onde eu saiba não tem como dar join em contextos diferentes

Comment: @LucasMiranda, no SQL Server pode utilizar Linked Server. Acho que usando o Entity Framework não tem como mesmo.